# VSCode - Chrome Debug - Unverified Breakpoint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with debugging my angular component inside .ts file.
I'm using VSCode and Debugger for Chrome extension.

Here is my vscode launch file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:5000",
            "sourceMaps": true, 
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"        
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compile": true,
  "comments":true,
  "module": "none",
  "target": "es5",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "mapRoot": "",
  "declaration": false
}
```

Inside angular component, I've set a breakpoint in $onInit cycle:

```
$onInit = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //here I put breakpoint
    let t = i;
  }
}
```

Debus starts successfully (chrome opens) but nothing happens. In my editor, if I hover over breakpoint, the tooltip shows with a message:
**Unverified breakpoint. Breakpoint set but not yet bound**

I am using 1.24.1 version of vscode.

Answer (score 5):

When using `Visual Studio Code > Open Folder...`, make sure you open the folder in which `package.json` is located.

Comment: I have a similar problem (version 1.28.2), but this has no effect.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, took me half an hour to find this. An alternative is to add the path to package.json in the webRoot property. EG: "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/client"